# Getting erorr "Can't load search results" in fragment

Tags: android, google-places-api

I created API key, quota < 1k p/day, but still getting error "Can't load search results"

Activity code:

```
Places.initialize(this, key);

    placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    final AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteSupportFragment =
            (AutocompleteSupportFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);



autocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields
(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME));

    autocompleteSupportFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new 
PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
            final String name = place.getName();

            Log.d("lol", name);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
        }
    });
```

And layout code where fragment is:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"       
 android:name=
"com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I expect city name in log

Comment: is there more error info than "Can't load search results"? Like an error code or key?

Comment: pls share an url of the api call or a postman sharable (zip)

Comment: @FaZeUnempl0yedd it's just "Can't load search results" and "Try again"

Comment: can you share an url or a postman save file?

Comment: Do you have billing and the Places API enabled on your project? Did you add the API key from your project and is it properly restricted? Please double check. And share your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by enabling billing account in google cloud console.